# How to handle one subclass have a method, while another subclass that doesn't have it?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, subclass, factory

I have a question about Interface, let's say:

```
class IAnimal
{ ...
Public:
    virtual void makeSound() = 0;
};

class Cat : public IAnimal
{  ...
    void makeSound() { std::cout << "purr" << std::endl; }
};
class Dog : public IAnimal
{  ...
    void makeSound() { std::cout << "bark" << std::endl; }
};
class AnimalFactory
{
    std::shared_ptr<IAnimal> createAnimal(animalType type)
    {  
        std::shared_ptr<IAnimal> animal;
        switch(type)
        { case animal_type::cat: animal = std::shared_ptr<Cat>(); break; 
          case animal_type::dog: animal = std::shared_ptr<Dog>(); break; 
        … }
        return animal;
    }
};

class App
{ ...
    std::shared_ptr<IAnimal> _animal;
    AnimalFactory::animal_type type;
    void haveCat()
    { ...
        type = AnimalFactory::animal_type::cat;
        _animal = AnimalFactory.createAnimal(type);
        _animal->makeSound();
        ...
    } 
};
```

now, I need this cat to catch a mouse
    void catchMouse()
    { std::cout << "catch a mice"; }

```
void haveCat()
{ ...
  type = AnimalFactory::animal_type::cat;
  _animal = AnimalFactory.createAnimal(type);
  _animal->makeSound();
  // catchMouse();
  ...
}
```

There are several possible solutions, but neither looks good.

1. add a method in IAnimal, then after create a cat using AnimalFactory, I can call catchMouse() method from IAnimal.
   but catchMouse is not for all animal, dog don't catchMouse. Adding a method into IAnimal pollutes the interface, smell code.
2. add a public method catchMouse() in Cat, and cast _animal to Cat in haveCat() method.

   ```
   {
   _cat = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Cat>(AnimalFactory.createAnimal(type));
   _cat->makeSound();
   _cat->catchMouse();
   }
   ```

   but there is a dynamic cast, not good, right?
3. let Cat implement IAnimal interface, and another Interface about Mouse, but AnimalFactory only return std::shared_ptr,
   and we can't call catchMouse in IAnimal.

What I am saying here is, there is a public method in one subclass, but another subclass doesn't have, how to design it, if we use factory.
Please don't reply, let the dog catch a rabbit, then add a catch() method in IAnimal, so, cat can catch mouse, dog can catch rabbit.

What is the good solution for this question? Thanks.

Comment: Why be so specific? Something like `find_food`, `collect_food`, `consume_food` should suffice.

Comment: `makeSound` looks like it should be a virtual function.

Comment: You've answered your own question with #2. When you need a cat, you have to cast it.

Comment: This sounds like abuse of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: You need to at least use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` in order to keep the reference count in the `std::shared_ptr`s correct.

Comment: If you are going to do explicit branches based on type, might just as well throw away all that object-orientation nonsense and say `switch (animal->type) { case CAT: ...` like real men did back when they wrote real programs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually cast from shared_ptr to Cat, can you? So without knowledge of your code base I've written a small test program,

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class IAnimal
{ 
public:
   virtual void makeSound(){}
};

class Cat : public IAnimal
{  
public:
    virtual void makeSound() { std::cout << "purr" << std::endl; }
    void catchMice(void){
        std::cout<<"mouse catched\n";
    }
};
class Dog : public IAnimal
{  
    virtual void makeSound() { std::cout << "bark" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    Cat* c = new Cat;
    std::shared_ptr<IAnimal> s(c);
    //you've basically got something of this sort don't you?
    s->makeSound();
    (static_cast<Cat*>(s.get()))->catchMice();
    return 0;
}
```

that should do what you want. I reckon you might want to have makeSound(void) as a virtual function.

Comment: Please focus on the question, you can use smart_pointer.get() to do the cast, or even don't use smart pointer. or use dynamic_pointer_cast; anyway, thanks.

Comment: didn't that answer your question? You want to access a child-class only function through a base class pointer, don't you? You cast it to a child class pointer and the compiler will generate call to the function at compile time.

Comment: Sorry, I see your answer, you mean using cast to cast IAnimal to Cat? like solution #2. Thanks.

Comment: Well, minus the dynamic casting. Since only Cats can catch mice, you know what you're casting into at compile time, so using static_cast will avoid the overhead introduced by dynamic_cast, which was your main concern. Or even a cast like this: (Cat*)(s->get()) like in Classic C will work fine in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the way to handle the problem is the variation of your solution 2: make a specific interface ICatcher with special method catch and do something like:

```
AnimalFactory::animal_type type = AnimalFactory::animal_type::cat;
std::shared_ptr<IAnimal> animal = myAnimalFactory.createAnimal(type);
(dynamic_cast<ICatcher*>(animal.get()))->catch();
```

But here you should be sure the dynamic_cast would be successful or provide additional check for that.

Maybe, you would also interested in how this problem is solved in  [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) by the super interface [IUnknown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUnknown) and its QueryInterface method. It's possible to implement the local version for that architecture.